# Cheapest most accessible shoutcasting solution

Tags: audio, shoutcast, internet-radio

I want to broadcast a looped 24/7 uninterrupted audio file across the internet in the cheapest and most accessible way. By accessiblity I mean a native browser from any OS can play it without any additional downloads of plugins/players, etc. I would like any computing device that can play audio, and can open an HTTP link, to be able to listen in. The audio is 2 hours and 30 mins long, and the file is currently sitting at 145MB encoded in MP3 format at 44100Hz, 128Kbps, 2 channel stereo, 32-bits.

The audio will be accessed by simply visiting a public HTTP webpage where it will begin streaming upon joining, without links, or even a transport to stop/play/rewind/fast forward the clip. Users stop the stream by closing the page. It will allow as many listeners as the bandwidth allows without loss of quality. I'm forecasting 10 simultaneous listeners will be the max at this time.

I don't think buying a Shoutcasting service is for me as they include alot of bells and whistles that I don't need for my barebones setup. Plus, I don't want to force people into downloading some type of player.

Here's a recap of my questions:

1. Is MP3 format really the one I want? If I have a better guarantee of accessibility with WAV I may consider it despite it's filesize; I don't expect listeners to stay through the entire 2 hours 30 mins duration anyways.
2. Should I pay for a shoutcasting service or can I set it all up myself with some free shoutcasting server software?

Answer (score 0):

If you want compatibility, SHOUTcast isn't for you.  It isn't fully compatible with HTTP which prevents usage on a lot of devices and browsers.  Icecast is more compatible.  You can host it yourself if you want, or you may be able to find a cheap hosting service for similar cost.

MP3 is a very compatible codec, but not everything supports it.  To be most compatible, you need to stream multiple codecs at the same time.  MP3, AAC, and Ogg-Vorbis are the most compatible when all three are used together.